# Java: printing ArrayLists to file without [ ] ,

Tags: java

I'm printing ArrayLists.toString() to a file and this is the result

```
[FirstLine
, SecondLine
, ThirdLine
]
```

I would like to remove the [ ] and , from my output.
Should I use a for loop to print the content of my ArrayList or is there an alternative way ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use third-party libraries, you can just use `StringBuilder` and a for-each loop.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Item item : list) {
   sb.append(item.toString());
}
String output = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably a [foreach](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop.

```
for(Foo f : FooList) {
  // use f
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An *alternative* way would be something like (pseudo):

```
String listString = list.toString();
listString = listString.substring(1, listString.length() - 1) // or maybe -2
```

Which would remove the first and last character from the String representation of list.toString().
However, I'd recommend the foreach loop which has already been mentioned in the other answers, specifically the answer which includes the StringBuilder.

Comment: Doesn't remove the separating commas.